# testing multiple variables in a conditional ? Dom Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, if-statement, conditional-statements

The code below represents the idea I am trying to achieve but when I test it doesn't work, what would be the appropriate way to test if q1 and q2 is equal to true?

```
function processForm() {
  if(q1_valid = true && q2_valid = true){
    alert("yes");
    } else {
    alert("no");
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `==` (or `===`) for testing. `=` is assignment.

Comment: And if testing a variable that you know will be `true` or `false` you can omit the `== true` part entirely and just say `if (q1_valid && q2_valid)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use simple `=` in javascript (and most C-like languages), what happens is that you assign the variable, then return the result of said assignment.

For instance, take the code `a = b = true`. This can be split up into `a = (b = true)`. Now, if we only look at the part inside the parenthesis, you'll see that what it does is first set b to true, then return b. Then, outside the parenthesis it sets a to whatever b was (which ofcause is `true`), and returns the value of a. The value of a has nowhere to go, so it's simply dropped.

Now, if we go back to your if-test, what you end up with is basically this:

1. Set `q1_valid` to `true`.
2. return `true` (the value of q1_valid) to the `&&` operator.
3. `true` is valid for `&&` so it looks at right hand side.
4. Set `q2_valid` to `true`.
5. return `true` to the `&&`.
6. `&&` now has `true` on both sides. Returns `true`.

Test always passes. `q1_valid` and `q2_valid` will always be `true` after test is run.

The simple solution is to replace `=` with either `==` (equals) or `===` (type **and** value equals). Your if-check should look like one of the following:

1.

```
if(q1_valid == true && q2_valid == true)
```

2.

```
if(q1_valid === true && q2_valid === true)
```

Also, since working with booleans (values that are either true or false), the check for equality to true can be omitted altogheter. Another way to do this is simply like this:

```
if(q1_valid && q2_valid)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was a very clear and thought out answer. I value your contribution, this definitely helped!

Comment: Glad to hear. Also, you should look up a bit on the difference between `==` and `===` in javascript. Otherwise the fact that `null == undefined` and `0 == null` might hit you as a bit of a shock.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

You need to use two equals signs for comparison `==`

The variables don't exist in the function, you would need to pass them as parameters when calling the function

```
function processForm(q1_valid, q2_valid) {
  if(q1_valid == true && q2_valid == true){
    alert("yes");
    } else {
    alert("no");
  }
}
```

Comment: You're obviously right about not using the single `=`, though double or triple equals would fix the problem here. Note though that the variables might be defined further up the scope chain (up to and including being globals), so they don't need to be parameters.